# get all members of public group EXCEPT where they are managers if a member

Tags: apex, soql, role-hierarchy, public-group

I am using the below code to get the members of a public group, plus all the indirect members (either members of a child group, or associated by their role membership)

```
public class GetAllGroupMembers {

    public static Set<id> GetUserIdsFromGroup(Id groupId)
    {
    // store the results in a set so we don't get duplicates
    Set<Id> result=new Set<Id>();
    String userType = Schema.SObjectType.User.getKeyPrefix();
    String groupType = Schema.SObjectType.Group.getKeyPrefix();

    // Loop through all group members in a group
    for (GroupMember m : [Select Id, UserOrGroupId From GroupMember Where GroupId = :groupId])
    {
        // If the user or group id is a user
        if (((String)m.UserOrGroupId).startsWith(userType))
        {
            system.debug('its a user:');
            result.add(m.UserOrGroupId);
            }
        // If the user or group id is a group
        // Note: there may be a problem with governor limits if this is called too many times
        else if (((String)m.UserOrGroupId).startsWith(groupType))
        {
            system.debug('its a Group:');
            // Call this function again but pass in the group found within this group
            result.addAll(GetUSerIdsFromGroup(m.UserOrGroupId));
            }
        }   
        return result; 
    }

    public static Set<id> GetUserIdsFromGroupWithProxies(Set<Id> groupIds){

        system.debug('GetUserIdsFromGroupWithProxies: ');            

        // store the results in a set so we don't get duplicates
        Set<Id> result=new Set<Id>();

        String userType = Schema.SObjectType.User.getKeyPrefix();
        String groupType = Schema.SObjectType.Group.getKeyPrefix();

        Set<Id> groupIdProxys = new Set<Id>();

        // Loop through all group members in a group
        for(GroupMember m : [Select Id, UserOrGroupId From GroupMember Where GroupId in :groupIds]){
            // If the user or group id is a user
            if(((String)m.UserOrGroupId).startsWith(userType)){            
                system.debug('Group Member ' + string.valueOf(m.UserOrGroupId) + ' is a user');
                result.add(m.UserOrGroupId);
                }

            // If the user or group id is a group
            // Note: there may be a problem with governor limits if this is called too many times
            else if (((String)m.UserOrGroupId).startsWith(groupType)){

                system.debug('Group Member ' + string.valueOf(m.UserOrGroupId) + ' is a group');
                // Call this function again but pass in the group found within this group
                groupIdProxys.add(m.UserOrGroupId);
                }
            }

        if(groupIdProxys.size() > 0){
            system.debug('adding ' + groupIdProxys.size() + ' proxies');
            result.addAll(GetUserIdsFromGroupWithProxies(groupIdProxys));
            }

        return result;  
    }    
}
```

The problem I am facing is that we specifically want to exclude those users who are members because they are the manager of a member...

**EDIT**:

In SalesForce when I look at **Setup** > **Users** > **Public Groups** > *Group_Name* > **View all users** I can see this column:

[image]
How can I restrict or exclude members who are in the group because they are the manager of a member?

Comment: Just a thought, since you can create groups that do not share w hierarchy, could you essentially clone the group, to a group without hierarchy sharing, and then check the delta w the original group, and these would be the folks who are in as managers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically, no, you can't do this with a simple query, as it also includes the manager's manager, the manager's manager's manager, etc... Basically, you'd need a second query to get everyone's role and the the role's parent role, then iterate over all those values and recursively remove the managers. While you *can* do this, it is non-trivial, because we are not given the tools to do this directly; the API only has the concept of "role" (which includes managers) and "role and subordinates" (which also includes users below the current role).

Comment: In salesforce, in the *Group* details pages under **View all users** there is a column called `Reason For Membership` - is there no way to access that field in the API?

Comment: I have edited and added a picture from salesforce showing the information I want to use in my api where clause or restriction code...